# Compiling FFMPEG on Windows using Wascana

Tags: eclipse, ffmpeg

Has anyone ever tried, or had any success at getting Wascana (Eclipse CDT + MinGW for Windows) to compile FFMPEG under Windows. Apparently it is possible, there is even a [tutorial at Craig Shaw's website](http://www.craigshaw.com/2007/07/25/BuildingFFMPEGUsingCDTForWindows.aspx) but I have not been able to make it work.

I run ./configure on the FFMPEG source code then create a new project in Eclipse and point it at the source but it doesn't recognise it as a Makefile project. I think I need to create a builder which works with MinGW but my feeble attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, I can answer my own question! After a lot of fiddling around, I have come up with the procedure:

*NOTE: This is for Wascana 0.9.3 and a Sep 2008 SVN version of FFMPEG.*

**Prepare Environment**

After installing Wascana, you'll need to update various MinGW and MSYS packages. Download and unpack the following (you can download them from the MinGW website):

MSYS packages:

- bash-3.1
- coreutils-5.97
- m4-1.4.7
- make-3.81

MinGW packages:

- w32api-3.12
- MinGW Runtime 3.15

**Build**

1. Unpack the FFMPEG source code and configure like so (do not compile it yet):

./configure --enable-memalign-hack --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-mmx --disable-mmx2 --disable-optimizations --disable-stripping

2. Launch Wascana/Eclipse and create a new C project.
3. Do not select "Hello World" project, just select a Makefile project and select the MinGW toolchain.
4. Set the project path to wherever your FFMPEG source code is.
5. Click finish and the source should build itself!

**Install**

1. Right click the project and select Make Targets > Create.
2. In the dialog, set both the Make Target and Target name to "install".
3. Run the target you just created. This will install the FFMPEG libraries.

**Execute and Debug**

1. Open the Debug Dialog
2. Right-click on "C/C++ Local Application" and choose "New"
3. Fill in the project name and select the EXE you want to run (in my case, ffplay_g.exe)
4. Go to the debugger tab and change the debugger to "MinGW gdb Debugger"

I also had to make sure a copy of SDL.dll was in the ffmpeg directory.

Phew, what an ordeal. That all worked for me, hopefully it will work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

install last MSYS and MinGW 
Cf. 
[link text](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.com/wiki/index.php?title=MSys_MinGW)

Comment: It worked for me with MSYS and MinGW versions from the linked I gave above and revision 16967 (03/02/09) of ffmpeg. Btw, ty to Adam ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the debugging I get "gdb.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close...."

I updated to gdb 6.8 and succeeded to debug